# Missing Annotation Processor with -XDdev leads to successful build without building class files

Tags: java, netbeans, annotations, javac

I was running into a curious problem today and would like to get some more info on that, as my google-fu proved to be insufficient for that.

## What happened

The scenario is as follows: I have a straightforward Netbeans project, which contains a `.java` file that makes use of some annotations, which are handled by the Netbeans annotation processor (`org.openide.filesystems.annotations.LayerGeneratingProcessor` to be precise) to create a `.xml` file during compilation.

All of this worked fine up until today, when I accidentally forgot to add the dependency for the annotation processor to my new project (i.e. `core/org-openide-filesystems.jar`). Without that dependency being present I witnessed the strangest behavior: a build (via Netbeans as well as directly via ant on the commandline) would report to be successful, yet no `.class` files were generated at all.

What really threw me off was that the build call come back with a success. Not a single warning or other indicator that something was amiss.. just no classes generated and a tiny little `.jar` file that only contained the `Bundle.properties` files, but again no `.class` files.

## The workaround

So much for the scenario itself. After a while I eventually came to find out about a `javac` option that would lead the compiler to finally tell me that something went wrong: `-XDdev`. I have never seen this option before and from my googling all I could find was that these kind of options are referred to as *Hidden Options*. But I haven't found a good listing of what hidden options are available and what they're good for. Any reference on that would be much appreciated.

Anyways, adding this option to the compile, the actual `javac` call would spit out a large stacktrace that eventually boils down to a `ClassNotFoundException` for the `LayerGeneratorProcessor` class. Lo and behold, once I added the dependency for that class to the project everything builds fine again.

## The remaining problem

What is funny (as in *scary*) is that even despite this exception being printed to stderr and indicating that annotation processing failed, the overall javac call succeeds! It still comes back with build successful and acts as if everything was fine. Without the `-XDdev` option, one would not even have any indication at all from the output that something went wrong.

Finally, my actual question: is there some way to turn this behavior into a proper error? While `-XDdev` is fine to find out the problem, it requires you to look at the build output, which especially in a CI context will not be feasible. I would like to protect others and myself from accidentally forgetting the dependency in the future by somehow switching this behavior to a proper build error such that we are also notified by the CI system in those cases.